# Implement blend and overlay with processingjs

Tags: javascript, processing, processing.js

I'm a little bit confused with processinjs library. What I need is processing two images using overlay. First image as a background and the second one with overlay effect to have finally a nice result. Basically what I have in my code is:

**HTML**

```
<img src="background.png" />
<img src="imageoverlay.png"/>
```

**JS**

```
PImage img = loadImage("background.png");
PImage img2 = loadImage("imageoverlay.png"); 
img.blend(img2, 0, 0, 33, 100, 67, 0, 33, 100, OVERLAY); 
image(img, 0, 0);
image(img2, 0, 0);
```

Does anyone know how to ini `PImage` in order to get this code works?

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to ensure the images are actually available. loadImage in Processing.js is just a wrapper for requestImage, so you'll need to use the `/* @pjs preload="..." */` syntax. See http://processingjs.org/reference/preload/